# How to make a custom select option menu style without image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, menu, html-select

[I don't want the Unicode character]
For example: With using Black down-pointing triangle.

It'll using `-webkit-appearance: none;` to make it look better.

It would be simple as:

`Select ▼`

to

`Select ▼`

`Value1`

`Value2`

or something similar

HTML:

```
<select>
  <option>Value1</option>
  <option>Value2</option>
</select>
```

**QUESTION:** How to do it in pure CSS, without any JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select boxes are not really styleable, so I wouldn't be surprised if this was impossible. Some limited styling options are available, but even they are unreliable. The only way to effectively style a select box is via jQuery and, unfortunately, images. My favourite form styling plugin is this [Uniform](http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/) - maybe it's worth to have a look at it.

I came up with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WQcud/1/) pure HTML, hacky solution, but it sucks. The arrow catches mouse events before they reach the select box. You'd need to do some hacking to eliminate that.

Comment: Yeah, it really is. Impossibility just went through my mind. But it's way much better than this http://jsfiddle.net/hedaru/YZXcj/. The select text sticks with the character. How about using "span" rather than "p"?

Comment: And unfortunately, the plugin is using image for that. And it's not pure css.

Comment: I guess span is OK too, it wouldn't even need the display:block thing, as it's an inline element :). Uniform does indeed work on images. If it's inconvenient for you, then indeed it's not what you're looking for :(.

Comment: Yeah, it really is. Oh, I just know we don't need display:block for a span. Cool thanks for your help. :D

Comment: Oh, ouch, I just noticed that I had written `display:block`, while the `p` element had `display:inline` :D. I meant that `p` is a blick level element and requires `display:inline`, while `span` is displayed inline by default :). I guess you got that anyway, I just hate being imprecise :).

Answer (score 2):

You can see [here](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2609-customizing-web-forms-with-css3-and-webkit) a css only solution, available only for webkit

Comment: Too bad it will mess up everything that's not webkit-powered. Styling form elements is especially hilarious in IE, and Opera will just give you the finger if you try it :D. Still, thanks for the link, it's definitely an interesting read.

Comment: Actually all form elements are kinda tricky to style. I always prefer to let them... pure, and avoid using all weird tricks.

Comment: Well... Not really. They are using embeded image (i'm not sure if this is the correct name though). No extra request is made to the server. :)

Comment: Embedded Image? (double d) :) Some other forum told that. I see, that can be a good solution if I can't find further completion for not using any image. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look here http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/ I not old-browser-friendly, but i guess you don't care to much if you go with this solution :)

Comment: @Ionut: Yeah, that can be the other way. Unfortunately, it doesn't look good in the code.

Comment: Code is for machine. If you really want to read smth, grab a book :)